# About using google client api

Tags: java, blogs, google-api-java-client

I am planning to write a native java application that can get some blogs by searching with a few words. And I know we can get some results by searching on google blog search. So I want to know if I can write such an application by using google blog search. But I found that google seems just offer a javascript API for its blog search. So could anyone tell me how to use google's blog search service in java?

If it's not possible, do you guys know some other services that can do similar thing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Google's blog platform is [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/), and it provides an API for working with the blogs on that platform. In addition, there are a number of client libraries for this API, including Java.

Here's some resources to help you get started:

- [Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Blogger_API) you can download the Java client library for the Blogger API
- [Here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/) is the documentation for the Blogger API in general.

  - You can see information on the different types of API calls you can make [here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started#background-operations).
- [And here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/blogger/v3/) is a link to the APIs-explorer for the Blogger API, where you can play around with its capabilities
- If you're new to using the Google Java Client Libraries for accessing Google APIs, you may also want to look at the documentation for the client libraries in general, [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/DeveloperGuide)

It looks like by default, the API only supports searching for posts in a given blog, not across all blogs, so you may need to do something clever to achieve your end goal (but it wouldn't be fun if it was given all away for free, right?)